# Django static url auto prefixes

Tags: python, django, static, redactor.js

I've seen quite alot of questions & answers on this topic, but none helped me.
So, the problem is: none of static files are served till i manually add '/' before any adress in adresses in html.
And i always get double static files folder prefix on adresses, like this: 'content/static/content/static/js/my.js'

The last problem, that i CANT get over, is this image cropping field isnt working, i assume becouse it cant get right image url, becouse of double prefix written above. I cant fix it, becouse the mechanism is written inside the https://github.com/jonasundderwolf/django-image-cropping. Is there a way to change this django behavior? In the redactor field i had same problem, but i fixed it with manually overwriting save() method, changing the url of uploaded images so they begin to be displayed, but it doesnt work automatically and i cant understand why.
Help please.

I tried {% static 'some_file' %}, sometimes its working, sometimes not, so its not a solution.

So, my django project structure is this:

1. project

   - content

     - templates
     - static
     - etc
   - project

project/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include ('content.urls')),
    url(r'^redactor/', include('redactor.urls')),
]

from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'content',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'redactor',
    'pure_pagination',
    'django_cleanup',
    'image_cropping',
    'easy_thumbnails',
)

from easy_thumbnails.conf import Settings as thumbnail_settings
THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS = (
    'image_cropping.thumbnail_processors.crop_corners',
) + thumbnail_settings.THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

STATIC_URL = '/content/static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = ( 
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__),
    ),
    "C:/Work/Snejana/magazine31.01.2016/content/static/upload_images",
    "C:/Work/Snejana/magazine31.01.2016/content/static",
    "C:/Work/Snejana/magazine31.01.2016",
)
```

one model from content/models.py:

```
class Author(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Автора'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Авторы'

    author_name              = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=u'Имя автора')
    regalias                 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, verbose_name=u'Регалии')
    description              = RedactorField(blank=True,
                                             verbose_name=u'Описание автора',
                                             redactor_options={'lang': 'en', 'focus': 'true'},
                                             upload_to='content/static/upload_images/',
                                             allow_file_upload=True,
                                             allow_image_upload=True)
    photo_full               = models.ImageField(upload_to="content/static/upload_images/",
                                                 verbose_name=u'Фото',
                                                 default=None,
                                                 blank=True,
                                                 null=True)
    photo_thumbnail          = models.ImageField(upload_to="content/static/upload_images/",
                                                 verbose_name=u'Фото маленькое',
                                                 default=None,
                                                 blank=True,
                                                 null=True)
    publications_of_author   = models.ForeignKey('Publication', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=u'Публикации автора')
    cropping1 = ImageRatioField('photo_full', '600x400')
    cropping2 = ImageRatioField('photo_thumbnail', '100x80')
```

And last one, admin.py:

```
class AuthorAdmin(ImageCroppingMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Информация об авторе', {'fields': ['author_name', 'description', 'photo_full', 'photo_thumbnail','cropping1', 'regalias'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    readonly_fields = ('photo_thumbnail',)
    inlines = [AuthorsPublicationsInline]

    class Media:
        js = ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js', 'js/collapsed_stacked_inlines.js',]
```

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Are you using the `collectstatic` management utility? Also, I think `STATICFILES_DIRS` is traversed recursively, so you only need to define `C:/Work/Snejana/magazine31.01.2016` and not the other two.

Comment: The other two are desperation ones, not necessible ofc.
I dont use collectstatic in this project, but i tried it before and it doesnt help. Same as placing {% load staticfiles %} in custom admin templates aswell as in all site templates. It doesnt resolve the problem until i manually add '/' to the hardcoded url's beginning manyally.

Answer (score 1):

Your `upload_to` attributes should not include the prefix; they are relative to MEDIA_ROOT.

```
photo_full = models.ImageField(upload_to="upload_images/", ...)
```

Comment: But if i dont define a `MEDIA_ROOT` ?
Or i have not single static folder, but one for each app?

Comment: You must define one. And you can have app-specific folders, but they must be under MEDIA_ROOT.

Comment: Now tried.
It creates the image same way as before, in same location, but it still doesnt work, images dont show up in admin.
Doesnt work, becouse adresses that are computed are relative to current adress of user, that tries to change something in some model.
So its like site/admin/change/model/1/upload_images/image
And this application doesnt add '/' before relative path for path to be computed from root domain, not from /admin/change/model/1